# Successful .htaccess URL rewrite - what next?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am rewriting:

```
example.com/food-truck.php?id=1
```

to:

```
example.com/truck/1
```

Using:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# redirect "/food-truck.php?id=xxx" to "/truck/xxx"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/food-truck\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /truck/%1? [R=301,L]
```

My rewrite it working, resulting in `example.com/truck/1`, however...I get a 404 Not Found on the resulting page, saying "the requested URL was not found on this server."

Is there something I am missing, or something incorrect with my rewrite? Do I need to have a "destination file" of some sort to interpret the redirect and display an output?

Comment: your going the wrong way you want it so when you hit `/truck/1` your rewriting to `/food-truck.php?id=1`, what you have is simply a redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an additional rule for rewrite:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# redirect "/food-truck.php?id=xxx" to "/truck/xxx"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/food-truck\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /truck/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^truck/\d+/?$ food-truck.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: It works, thank you! Any recommendation for extracting, or "getting", the id back out of the url to use within the food-truck.php page using PHP?

Comment: Sorry didn't get your question. These 2 rules are already doing that.

Comment: Basically, $_GET['id'] no longer works after the URL rewrite. I need to use the ID to query the database, display results, etc. Should $_GET['id'] still be providing me with a result, or is there an alternative method I should use with the new url?